# C#: an UriFormatException is thrown when I call a JSONAPI function

Tags: c#, exception

When I call the function 'callmultiple' of the JSONAPI Library (http://mcjsonapi.com/), an UriFormatExeption is thrown. However when I call the 'call' function, all works. Below i give you the code That produce an error:

```
JSONAPI j = new JSONAPI("minecraft20.omgserv.com", 40174, "username","password", "salt");
Dictionary<Object,Object> result = j.call("getServer",null); //all works
Dictionary<Object,Object) result2 = j.callMultiple(new string[] {"getServer", "getOfflinePlayers"},null) //UriFormatException is thrown
```

stacktrace:

```
 System.UriFormatException n'a pas été gérée
    HResult=-2146233033
    Message=invalid uri : the authority/host could not be parse
    Source=System
    Stacktrace:
        at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
        at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
        at com.ramblingwood.minecraft.jsonapi.JSONAPI.makeURLMultiple(IEnumerable methods, IEnumerable args)
        at com.ramblingwood.minecraft.jsonapi.JSONAPI.callMultiple(IEnumerable methods, IEnumerable args)
        at MineControl.Server.Server.UpdateServer() dans c:\Users\frank\Documents\GitHub\MineControl\MineControl\Server\Server.cs:ligne 102
        at MineControl.Server.Server..ctor(String host, Int32 port, String id, String password, String salt) dans c:\Users\frank\Documents\GitHub\MineControl\MineControl\Server\Server.cs:ligne 56
        at MineControl.App..ctor() dans c:\Users\frank\Documents\GitHub\MineControl\MineControl\App.xaml.cs:ligne 26
        at MineControl.App.Main() dans c:\Users\frank\Documents\GitHub\MineControl\MineControl\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:ligne 0
        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
    InnerException:
```

I don't understand why this code is bad, so Please help me.
 thanks you

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Exception message: invalid uri: the authority/host could not be parse

Comment: Stacktrace: at System.Uri.CreateThis(string uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)

Comment: System.Uri..ctor(string uriString)

Comment: at com.ramblingwood.minecraft.jsonapi.JSONAPI.makeURLMultiple(IEnumerable méthode, IEnumerable args)

Comment: at com.ramblingwood.minecraft.jsonapi.JSONAPI.callMultiple(IEnumerable methods, IEnumerable args)

Comment: at Minecontrol.Server.Server.UpdateServer()

Comment: At Minecontrol.Server.Server..ctor()

Comment: What are the values of `host`, `port`, and the other arguments you pass to the JSONAPI function? Also, *edit your question* to add the stack trace information and the information I just asked for.

Comment: It's done, i've added informations You ask me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the problem, but the documentation says that `callMultiple` will throw an exception if the length of the `methods` array and the length of the `args` array are different.

You have:

```
Dictionary<Object,Object) result2 = 
    j.callMultiple(new string[] {"getServer", "getOfflinePlayers"}, null);
```

It's quite possible that you need to write:

```
Dictionary<Object,Object) result2 = 
    j.callMultiple(new string[] {"getServer", "getOfflinePlayers"}, 
                   new string[] {null, null});
```

That's what I'd try, anyway.

Comment: No, I have the same exception when I write this, any other idea ?

Comment: @fr4nky890: That was my only idea. Sorry.